# Matrix-Vector Multiplication on MPI - ERROR Compiled code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi

I need assistance to resolve an error in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;
//matrix in two dimension in memory!!
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int WIDTH = 100;
    const int HEIGHT = 100;
    int id, P;
    double tempValue = 0;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &P);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
    double A[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    double x[HEIGHT], b[WIDTH];
    int upperBound, lowerBound = 0;
    // Master controls worksharing..
    if (id == 0)
    {
        // Init A & x
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                A[i][j] = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
            x[j] = 2;
        // Send to each node its portion of A to be processed
        int portionSize = WIDTH / P;
        for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
        {
            lowerBound = i * portionSize;
            upperBound = (i + 1) * portionSize;
            // let the last node process the remainder
            if (i == (P - 1))
                upperBound += (HEIGHT - portionSize * P);
            if (i > 0)// Do not send to master node!!
            {
                // Send to node i the lower & upper bounds the A portion
                //and complete vector x
                MPI_Send(&lowerBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&upperBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&A[lowerBound][0], (upperBound - lowerBound) * HEIGHT,
                    MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Send(&x[0], HEIGHT, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
        // master perform part of the job...
        for (int i = 0; i < portionSize; i++)
        {
            tempValue = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                tempValue += A[i][j] * x[j];
            b[i] = tempValue;
        }
        //Get the results in order, each node would send their boundaries and data part
        for (int i = 1; i < P; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&lowerBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&upperBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&P[lowerBound], (upperBound - lowerBound), MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        }
        // Print the first 2 values to check..
        cout << "b[0]=" << b[0] << " b[Width-1]=" << b[WIDTH - 1] << endl;
    }
    else // the rest of the workers do their parts
    {
        //Receive the inputs
        MPI_Recv(&lowerBound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&upperBound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&A[lowerBound][0], (upperBound - lowerBound) * WIDTH, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        MPI_Recv(&x, HEIGHT, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        cout << "Node:" << id << " Received from:" << lowerBound << " to " << upperBound - 1
            << endl;
        double* result = new double[upperBound - lowerBound];
        //Do the job
        for (int i = lowerBound, resultCounter = 0; i < upperBound; i++, resultCounter++)
        {
            tempValue = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                tempValue += A[i][j] * x[j];
            result[resultCounter] = tempValue;
        }
        //send the results
        MPI_Send(&lowerBound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&upperBound, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&result[0], upperBound - lowerBound, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        delete[] result;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, I get this error message:

> Error (active)    E0142   expression must have pointer-to-object type ConsoleApplication9 C:\Users\m_swe\Desktop\Assignments\Assignments\PrjP2P\MatMPI\MatMPI\Source.cpp  59
>   Error   C2109   subscript requires array or pointer type    ConsoleApplication9 C:\Users\m_swe\Desktop\Assignments\Assignments\PrjP2P\MatMPI\MatMPI\Source.cpp  59

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on *line: 59*

> ```
>        MPI_Recv(&P[lowerBound], (upperBound - lowerBound), MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0,
> ```

`MPI_Recv` takes in a pointer to a buffer (the first argument) where you are going to receive and store the incoming data. In this case it could be in some variable which you can define inside the for loop, as:

```
int receivedValues[ WIDTH * HEIGHT ];
for (int i = 1; i < P; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&lowerBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&upperBound, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&receivedValues[0], (upperBound - lowerBound), MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

           // do your computation here with receivedValues
        }
}
```